# How do I call a method from a superclass, whos definition is completely deferred to the subclasses?

Tags: python

I want to envoke a method in my code in a supercass, to do some subclass- specific processing before continuing on. I come to python recently from C#... there, I'd probably use an interface. Here's the gist of it (as I picture it, but it's not working):

```
class superClass:
    def do_specific_stuff(self): #To be implemented entirely by the subclass, 
        #but called from the superclass
        pass

    def do_general_stuff1(self):
        #do misc

    def do_general_stuff2(self):
        #do more misc

    def main_general_stuff(self):
        do_general_stuff1()
        do_specific_stuff()
        do_general_stuff2()
```

I have a rather complicated implementation of this; this example is exactly what I need and far less painful to understand for a first- time viewer. Calling `do_specific_stuff()` at the moment gives me the error

'global name 'do_specific_stuff' is not defined.

When I add 'self' as in `self.do_specific_stuff` I get the error

'TypeError: do_specific_stuff() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.'  Any takers? Thanks in advance...

Comment: As a side note: You don't need to have a `do_specific_stuff` method in the base class at all. There's no "virtual and non-virtual methods" in Python or anything like that; every method is looked up on the subclass first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be

```
def main_general_stuff(self):
    self.do_general_stuff1()
    self.do_specific_stuff()
    ...
```

The problem is that you are missing the explicit reference to `self`: Python thinks you mean a global function without it. Note that there is no implicit `this` like in Java: You need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but I just updated my post to the new error. A passed argument error.

Comment: Regarding the `TypeError` in your update:  Do you have an implementation of `do_specific_stuff` in one of your subclasses with a different (zero-argument) signature?

Comment: @statsviacsh you probably forgot to define it as `def do_specific_stuff(self):`  check that the `self` argument is present in your subclass

Comment: Vikki, you nailed it. I'd accept if I could. Greenhorn mistake. Thx.